# Google Group members not visible in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-groups

In my Google Workspace, I added an internal Google Group to an internal Google Calendar event but I am not able to unfurl the participant/invitee list for the group, even though the group should be accessible. This happens without regard to my group permissions status. How do I fix this?

Comment: This question was bumped by the Community User. The question doesn't mention if you are the owner, admin or basic group member. It doesn't mention the type of Group, i.e., if it is email only, web only, etc., if it was created with a newly created or well-established account, among other things that might be relevant.

Comment: This ostensibly applies to all kinds of groups in setting who can view members. It works regardless of the event editor's permissions, as this still happens even if they are an admin.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. I don't understand what you mean by the term *"group permissions status"*  Please [edit] to clarify your specific role in the group (Owner; Manager; Member).

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Group's settings, change "who can view member email addresses" from "Group members" to "Entire organization", as the former setting hides the guest list in calendar invites.

[image: Member privacy]